# Repeating regex Optimize

Tags: regex

I have the following text to be matched:

```
22536H34-TH65-GH32-HE762H23H982
```

And my regex is as follows:

https://regex101.com/r/XwNXZb/1

How can this be further optimized?

Comment: There is no lookaround involved. Optimize for what? You can simplify to `\w{8}-\w{4}-\w{4}-\w{12}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to validate exactly the pattern with example `22536H34-TH65-GH32-HE762H23H982` you should:

- anchor the string with `^` ... `$`, otherwise a sring like `===22536H34-TH65-GH32-HE762H23H982===` would validate too
- instead of `\w`, use a character class that spells out the allowed characters, such as `[0-9A-Z]`

Here are the two changes combined:

```
^[0-9A-Z]{8}-[0-9A-Z]{4}-[0-9A-Z]{4}-[0-9A-Z]{12}$
```

You could further group the two repeating patterns in the middle:

```
^[0-9A-Z]{8}-(?:[0-9A-Z]{4}-){2}[0-9A-Z]{12}$
```